# Issue while reading single-band UInt16 GeoTIFF file using Geotools

Tags: geotiff-tiff, geotools

I'm facing a strange issue while trying to open GeoTIFF files using Geotools library.
Following simple code works for reading coverage in **Byte**, but raises an exception when I try to open **UInt16** encoded data.

```
AbstractGridFormat format = GridFormatFinder.findFormat( file );
GridCoverage2DReader reader = format.getReader( file );
File file = new File("someGeotiff.tif");

GeoTiffReader reader = new GeoTiffReader(file, new Hints(Hints.FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER, Boolean.TRUE));

GridCoverage2D coverage = (GridCoverage2D) reader.read(null);
```

GeoTools stacktrace looks like this. The fact the file is a COG has no impact. The problem also happens on classic GeoTIFF files.

```
org.geotools.data.DataSourceException: Bad value for bits!
at org.geotools.gce.geotiff.GeoTiffReader.<init>(GeoTiffReader.java:283)
at org.geotools.gce.geotiff.GeoTiffFormat.getReader(GeoTiffFormat.java:334)
at org.geotools.gce.geotiff.GeoTiffFormat.getReader(GeoTiffFormat.java:303)
at org.geotools.gce.geotiff.GeoTiffFormat.getReader(GeoTiffFormat.java:77)
```

Here is relevant gdalinfo data:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: T31TCJ_20230405T105031_B03_60m.tif
Size is 1830, 1830
[...]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
Origin = (300000.000000000000000,4900020.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (60.000000000000000,-60.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=DEFLATE
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
  LAYOUT=COG
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  300000.000, 4900020.000) (  0d29'45.34"E, 44d13'33.47"N)
Lower Left  (  300000.000, 4790220.000) (  0d32'12.38"E, 43d14'17.75"N)
Upper Right (  409800.000, 4900020.000) (  1d52'12.85"E, 44d14'52.19"N)
Lower Right (  409800.000, 4790220.000) (  1d53'19.26"E, 43d15'33.81"N)
Center      (  354900.000, 4845120.000) (  1d11'52.46"E, 43d44'41.70"N)
Band 1 Block=512x512 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Gray
  Overviews: 915x915, 458x458, 229x229, 115x115
  Image Structure Metadata:
    NBITS=15
```

What am I missing?

Comment: which version of GeoTools are you using? [line 283](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/f0556d450f0ade2e7e98e6f1e94c95e2c57f5660/modules/plugin/geotiff/src/main/java/org/geotools/gce/geotiff/GeoTiffReader.java#LL283C1-L283C1) seems unlikely to throw that error on main

Comment: `NBITS=15` may be the problem. So called `UInt16` geotiffs can also actually be from 9-15 bits instead of 16. https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html#creation-options. You could convert to a full 16 bits with `gdal_translate`.

Comment: My GeoTools version is 27.2. As conversion to Int32 did the trick (at the expense of using more storage) I will try to convert to UInt16

Comment: According to the GDAL GeoTiff documentation, NBITS=15 is correct for a GeoTIFF with 16bits encoding. 
https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html
_NBITS=<value>: Create a file with less than 8 bits per sample by passing a value from 1 to 7. The apparent pixel type should be Byte. Values of n=9...15 (UInt16 type) and n=17...31 (UInt32 type) are also accepted. From GDAL 2.2, n=16 is accepted for Float32 type to generate half-precision floating point values._

Comment: @IanTurton, here is the [link to line 283](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/27.2/modules/plugin/geotiff/src/main/java/org/geotools/gce/geotiff/GeoTiffReader.java#LL283C1-L283C1) to the Exception thrown in the version 27.2

Comment: Ok, but I think that error is actually only rethrown by GeoTools and comes from the JDK code - maybe somewhere like https://github.com/vitrun/JDK1.8/blob/99bcdb45bafd260513c371fb64bb609f1d333deb/src/javax/imageio/ImageTypeSpecifier.java#L556 - is there more log file?